# Kivy issue "TypeError: Cannot convert str to kivy.properties.Property"

Tags: python, kivy

**Hello Everybody**

Okay, so I am currently attempting to create a Kivy app where you can enter student names and the names are appended to a list. I was following the tutorial on youtube by Derek Banas, and I decided that I also wanted to implement a functionality whereby the entered and deleted items would be saved in a text file, and that text file would be loaded back in the next time the app was started. I did not get this far due to the error listed in my title. The app runs just fine the first time, but when attempting to run it a second time, I get the TypeError issue. I am assuming it has something to do with me using a list to store the values in the text file, but I am not sure exactly why this error is appearing. Below is the entirety of my code thus far, including the .kv file.

*Note: I am aware that using a simple text file to store persistent data is not advisable or scaleable, but I am simply trying to become comfortable with Kivy, and I don't plan on releasing this in any sort of way, so no need to tell me I shouldn't be doing that, I already know D:*

**studentlist.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
import csv
import os


class StudentListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass


class StudentDB(BoxLayout):

    # Connects the value in the TextInput widget to these
    # fields
    file_name = "./saved_names.txt"
    first_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    last_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    students_list = ObjectProperty()
    file_write_list =[]

    print("beginning reading file")
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        read_write = 'r'
        names_file = open(file_name, read_write)
        for x in names_file:
            print("reading saved_names file")
            x = x.rstrip()
            file_write_list.append(x)
            print("First name appended to list")


    else:
        print("creating new saved_names file")
        read_write = 'w'
        names_file = open(file_name, read_write)
        names_file.write("")

    names_file.close()




    def submit_student(self):
        print("Submitting new student")
        # Get the student name from the TextInputs
        first_name_stripped = self.first_name_text_input.text.replace(" ", "")
        last_name_stripped = self.last_name_text_input.text.replace(" ","")
        student_name = first_name_stripped + " " + last_name_stripped

        # Add the student to the ListView
        self.students_list.adapter.data.extend([student_name])
        self.file_write_list.append(student_name)
        self.save_listt(self.file_write_list, self.file_name)
        # Reset the ListView
        self.students_list._trigger_reset_populate()

    def delete_student(self, *args):
        print("deleting student")
        # If a list item is selected
        if self.students_list.adapter.selection:

            # Get the text from the item selected
            selection = self.students_list.adapter.selection[0].text

            # Remove the matching item
            self.students_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)

            self.file_write_list.remove(selection)
            self.save_listt(self.file_write_list, self.file_name)
            # Reset the ListView
            self.students_list._trigger_reset_populate()

    def replace_student(self, *args):
        print("replacing student")
        # If a list item is selected
        if self.students_list.adapter.selection:

            # Get the text from the item selected
            selection = self.students_list.adapter.selection[0].text

            # Remove the matching item
            self.students_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)


            # Get the student name from the TextInputs
            student_name = self.first_name_text_input.text + " " + self.last_name_text_input.text

            # Add the updated data to the list
            self.students_list.adapter.data.extend([student_name])

            for i, x in enumerate(self.file_write_list):
                if x == selection:
                    self.file_write_list[i] = str(student_name)

            self.save_listt(self.file_write_list, self.file_name)
            # Reset the ListView
            self.students_list._trigger_reset_populate()

    def save_listt(self, list_name, file_name):
        print("Saving names list to saved_names file")
        file_w = open(self.file_name, 'w')
        for x in list_name:
            file_w.write(x + '\n')
        file_w.close()



class StudentDBApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return StudentDB()





dbApp = StudentDBApp()

dbApp.run()
```

**studentdb.kv**

```
# Reference studentlist.py
#: import main studentlist
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton


StudentDB:

<StudentDB>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    first_name_text_input: first_name
    last_name_text_input: last_name
    students_list: students_list_view
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"

        Label:
            text: "First Name"
        TextInput:
            id: first_name
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Last Name"
        TextInput:
            id: last_name
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.submit_student()
        Button:
            text: "Delete"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.delete_student()
        Button:
            text: "Replace"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.replace_student()

    ListView:
        id: students_list_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=["Doug Smith"], cls=main.StudentListButton)
```

Comment: So, save us some work and tell us which line in your code is generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is causing that error, but you can fix it by putting your initialization code in a `__init__()` method as:

```
class StudentDB(BoxLayout):

    # Connects the value in the TextInput widget to these
    # fields
    file_name = "./saved_names.txt"
    first_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    last_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    students_list = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StudentDB, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.file_write_list =[]

        print("beginning reading file")
        if os.path.exists(self.file_name):
            read_write = 'r'
            names_file = open(self.file_name, read_write)
            for x in names_file:
                print("reading saved_names file")
                x = x.rstrip()
                self.file_write_list.append(x)
                print("First name appended to list: " + x)
                self.students_list.adapter.data.extend([x])
        else:
            print("creating new saved_names file")
            read_write = 'w'
            names_file = open(self.file_name, read_write)
            names_file.write("")
            names_file.close()
```

Also, note that you are creating two `StudentDB` instances. One in your `kv` file (by virtue of the line `StudentDB:`), and one in your app `build` method. The easiest fix, is to just remove the `StudentDB:` line from your `kv` file.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. I was wondering why I was getting two of every output in the command line, I didn't think much of it though. I actually found out what the issue was, or at least I think I did. In my original .py file within the studentdb class, I was using x as a variable, which I am assuming is a property of the Kivy app class, thus, when I was using it as a variable, I was attempting to instantiate a kivy property with a string.

Comment: @Zachary, that could be the problem, and by putting it into a `__init__()` method, the `x` becomes a local variable and does not interfere with instance variables.

Comment: Okay great, I will make sure to use an` __init__()` method for that!